# CSS rendering in Outlook/Windows and Outlook/OS X

Tags: html, css, windows, macos, outlook

I have an HTML page which uses basic CSS elements such as float, padding, border, color, width etc. This page renders correctly on MS Outlook 15.19.1 on OS X Yosemite but most of the styling does not render on MS Outlook 2013 (15.0.4481.1510) on Windows 8.1 .

Is there a specific configuration to be done on MS Outlook 2013 on Windows to render CSS styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This -- http://www.sitepoint.com/tricks-building-responsive-email/ -- is a good reference for those who may have issues with rendering on Email clients. Seems to work for me so far.